# What results should I see from running initdb?

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-12

Running initdb looks pretty straightforward from the docs.
I created the data directory, checked the permisions on the folder, ran initdb as the postgres user, and entered the password.
It returns immediately.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12>runas /user:pgUser@domain "bin\initdb.exe -k -D \"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\""
Enter the password for pgUser@domain:
Attempting to start bin\initdb.exe -k -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" as user "pgUser@domain" ...

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12>
```

Results:
The data dir is still empty, no errors in the event log, and the service won't start.

I expected it to populate data with the base directories, create the postgres and template databases, and be able to start the database engine as a service.

Comment: 1)  Postgres 9.4 is almost 3 past EOL so I hope you are not using it. 2) How did you install Postgres? 3) What do the system logs show when you run this?

Comment: 1) My bad. You are right. This is 12. This is part of my attempt at upgrading from 9.4. 2) Running postgresql-12.10-2-windows-x64.exe. Should I just start over and run that again? 3) You may need to be more specific. No data\log directory and nothing in the event viewer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I reinstalled postgres and now the data dir is populated. But I still can't run initdb. Whether I have the service running or not, it just returns with no errors. Nothing in the log dir. Postgres database exists, just like before, but with no contents.

Comment: I was able to run pg_checksums and get the checksums enabled. Perhaps that's all I need.

Comment: If `\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\` is the data directory running `initdb` on it will fail as `initdb` will not run on a directory with files in it.  The `postgres` database will not have anything in it. It's purpose is to be a database you connect to to create the database or databases you want for your own use.

Comment: I recommend that you use an absolute path (`C:\.. `) rather than a relative path (`bin\...`).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Perhaps so, but it didn't run when 'data' was empty either. It is probably returning an error that 'runas' is obscuring.

Comment: You still have not said how you installed Postgres? Most installations will do an `initdb` as part of the install, are you not seeing that directory? Have you looked at the OS system logs for an error?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver When I start up the postgres server and it fails, it leaves an error in the windows event log. initdb does not. I expect that any errors are written to stdout or stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was three-fold.
First, as suspected, runas starts another process to run the command.
Redirecting, as such

```
runas /user:pgUser@domain "cmd" > output.txt
```

only redirects the output of runas.
To capture the output of the cmd, you need to redirect inside that process.

```
runas /user:pgUser@domain "cmd > output.txt 2>&1"
```

Second, installing postgres on windows includes initdb.
So, uninstalling and re-installing accomplished that.

Third, one of the things that I wanted to accomplish with the reset was enabling checksums and something I read said that you could only set that flag using initdb. But that's not true. You can enable checksums on an existing cluster.
So I didn't need to run initdb at all. In spite of so many recommendations to start with a freshly "initdb'd" installation.

Comment: That is because from Postgres 11 back to 9.3(when checksums where introduced) they had to enabled during the initial initdb.

Comment: That makes sense. That'll keep me from tripping over it if I have to do any more half steps in my upgrade process.